# The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. /home

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

I created a simple java application and installed tomcat (version 9.0.71), added a servlet dependency (version 5.0), and wrote the following

I created an html file and wrote these

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Haromi</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Jonim</h1>
<a href="/home">Home page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And I wrote this in web.xml and it should call Home class but......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>uz.pdp.Home</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsv8S.png)